# Remove rows with one column duplicated (not 'distinct')

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by, distinct

I'm using access, and I'm trying to write a query which will remove duplicates of one column. Here is my query so far:

```
SELECT
  Drawings.DrawingID,
  Players.NumOfGuessedAPainting,
  Players.NumOfGuessedBPainting,
  Players.NumOfGuessedCPainting,
  Words.Word
FROM Words INNER JOIN
    (Players INNER JOIN
    (Drawings INNER JOIN
     PlayersAndWords 
       ON Drawings.DrawingID = PlayersAndWords.DrawingID)
       ON Players.PlayerID = PlayersAndWords.DrawingPlayerID)
       ON Words.WordID = PlayersAndWords.WordID 
WHERE ((Words.Word)='" + w + "')
ORDER BY (Players.NumOfGuessedAPainting
         +Players.NumOfGuessedBPainting * 2
         +Players.NumOfGuessedCPainting *3 ) DESC
```

The column `Drawings.DrawingID` might be duplicated, and I want the query to return only one row of each Drawings.DrawingID. "distinct" won't work here. I've read that `group by` might help but I couldn't figure how..
Could you help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why won't distinct work?

Answer (score 0):

Just put these lined before ORDER BY line

```
GROUP BY
    Drawings.DrawingID,
    Players.NumOfGuessedAPainting,
    Players.NumOfGuessedBPainting,
    Players.NumOfGuessedCPainting,
    Words.Word
```

Edited.

Comment: this doesn't work. "you tried to execute a query thhat does not include the specific expression 'NumOfGuessedAPaintings' as part of the aggregate function

Comment: I guess I solved it, look again at my answer, I edited it. (notice "before")

Comment: try again, edited again. I didn't spot that it's all about MS Access base, I thought about MySQL.